# How to suppress messages from bash alias with pipe

Tags: bash, alias, zsh

I have this alias to kill all neovim instance:

```
alias killnvim="ps -ef | grep nvim | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill &> /dev/null"
```

Each time I run it it always return this message:

```
[1]    20958 done        ps -ef |
       20959 done        grep --color=auto nvim |
       20960 done        awk '{print }' |
       20961 terminated  xargs kill &> /dev/null
```

What should I do to suppress that message? I want my command to output nothing.

I'm using zsh if that matter.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use bash or zsh?

Comment: `killall nvim`?

Comment: @Cyrus No, it's not a workaround, using `killall` or even better, `pkill`, is the correct solution. `ps` and grepping the result is a hack.

Comment: I'm surprised `zsh` doesn't provide a way to do this with its built-in `kill` or via a module like `zkill`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a quoting problem. You need the {print $2} to be in single quotes so that the invocation of the alias doesn't replace the $2 with a value, and for the whole alias to be in single quotes to stop $2 being replaced at definition time.

zsh does allow two single quotes to be replaced by one quote in a single-quoted string, but you need to set an option to allow that.

More portable is to use the following:

```
alias killnvim='ps -ef | grep nvim | awk '"'"'{print $2}'"'"' | xargs kill &> /dev/null'
```

You could also escape any sensitive characters, but the above seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a good reason to use an alias, prefer a function:

```
killnvim () {
  ps -ef | grep nvim | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill &> /dev/null
}
```

(That said, there are better alternatives to rolling your own pipeline to kill a process by name.)